401 Unauthorized: web-scraping with requests python library
I'm trying to use an API from a database using the requests library. The code is working, but every now and then i have to go and remake my headers, because of an authorization error 401. Is there a way to reauthenticate or to get the fresh headers by code? Because if i need to go and get new headers every time, the code becomes meaningless.
url: Database.com
input
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import pandas as pd
url = "https://dw.ceasa.gov.br/saiku/rest/saiku/api/query/execute"

payload = json.dumps({
  "name": "0A777C63-EAF6-181A-9FB1-248AFCE90BE1",
  "queryModel": {
    "axes": {
      "FILTER": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "FILTER",
        "hierarchies": [],
        "nonEmpty": False,
        "aggregators": []
      },
      "COLUMNS": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "COLUMNS",
        "hierarchies": [
          {
            "name": "[04-Produto].[04-Produto]",
            "levels": {
              "Produto": {
                "name": "Produto"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "nonEmpty": True,
        "aggregators": []
      },
      "ROWS": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "ROWS",
        "hierarchies": [
          {
            "name": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano]",
            "levels": {
              "Ano": {
                "name": "Ano",
                "aggregators": [],
                "selection": {
                  "type": "EXCLUSION",
                  "members": [
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2015]",
                      "caption": "2015"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2016]",
                      "caption": "2016"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2017]",
                      "caption": "2017"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2018]",
                      "caption": "2018"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2019]",
                      "caption": "2019"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2020]",
                      "caption": "2020"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2021]",
                      "caption": "2021"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2022]",
                      "caption": "2022"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2023]",
                      "caption": "2023"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes]",
            "levels": {
              "Mes": {
                "name": "Mes",
                "aggregators": [],
                "selection": {
                  "type": "EXCLUSION",
                  "members": [
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[JANEIRO]",
                      "caption": "JANEIRO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[FEVEREIRO]",
                      "caption": "FEVEREIRO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[MARÇO]",
                      "caption": "MARÇO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[ABRIL]",
                      "caption": "ABRIL"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[MAIO]",
                      "caption": "MAIO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[JUNHO]",
                      "caption": "JUNHO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[2º SEM].[JULHO]",
                      "caption": "JULHO"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[08-Dia].[08-Dia]",
            "levels": {
              "Dia Mes": {
                "name": "Dia Mes"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "nonEmpty": True,
        "aggregators": []
      }
    },
    "visualTotals": False,
    "visualTotalsPattern": None,
    "lowestLevelsOnly": False,
    "details": {
      "axis": "COLUMNS",
      "location": "BOTTOM",
      "measures": []
    },
    "calculatedMeasures": []
  },
  "queryType": "OLAP",
  "type": "QUERYMODEL",
  "cube": {
    "uniqueName": "[Prohort].[Prohort].[Prohort].[PROHORT - PRECO DIARIO]",
    "name": "PROHORT - PRECO DIARIO",
    "connection": "Prohort",
    "catalog": "Prohort",
    "schema": "Prohort",
    "caption": None,
    "visible": False
  },
  "mdx": None,
  "parameters": {},
  "plugins": {},
  "properties": {
    "saiku.olap.query.automatic_execution": False,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty": True,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.rows": True,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.columns": True,
    "saiku.ui.render.mode": "table",
    "saiku.olap.query.filter": True,
    "saiku.olap.result.formatter": "flattened",
    "org.saiku.query.explain": True,
    "org.saiku.connection.scenario": False,
    "saiku.olap.query.drillthrough": True
  },
  "metadata": {}
})

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=EB000E928441CC372431FA5B47CB86F8',
  'Origin': 'https://dw.ceasa.gov.br',
  'Referer': 'https://dw.ceasa.gov.br/',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
}


response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.status_code)

output at first: 200
output the "next day": 401

Just noticed that the only thing that changes from the old to the new header is the cookie, no sure what that means.

Here's how to get the JSESSIONID:
import requests

session = requests.Session()

data = {
    'username': 'almir.costa',
    'password': '123123',
}

url = 'https://dw.ceasa.gov.br/saiku/rest/saiku/session'
response = session.post(url, data=data)

The post request will set the JSESSIONID cookie.
Use the session to make all your requests. A session will persists all cookies/headers across requests, you can add header to it with: session.headers = headers or session.headers.update(headers)

Here's the full code:
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import pandas as pd


payload = json.dumps({
  "name": "0A777C63-EAF6-181A-9FB1-248AFCE90BE1",
  "queryModel": {
    "axes": {
      "FILTER": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "FILTER",
        "hierarchies": [],
        "nonEmpty": False,
        "aggregators": []
      },
      "COLUMNS": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "COLUMNS",
        "hierarchies": [
          {
            "name": "[04-Produto].[04-Produto]",
            "levels": {
              "Produto": {
                "name": "Produto"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "nonEmpty": True,
        "aggregators": []
      },
      "ROWS": {
        "mdx": None,
        "filters": [],
        "sortOrder": None,
        "sortEvaluationLiteral": None,
        "hierarchizeMode": None,
        "location": "ROWS",
        "hierarchies": [
          {
            "name": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano]",
            "levels": {
              "Ano": {
                "name": "Ano",
                "aggregators": [],
                "selection": {
                  "type": "EXCLUSION",
                  "members": [
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2015]",
                      "caption": "2015"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2016]",
                      "caption": "2016"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2017]",
                      "caption": "2017"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2018]",
                      "caption": "2018"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2019]",
                      "caption": "2019"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2020]",
                      "caption": "2020"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2021]",
                      "caption": "2021"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2022]",
                      "caption": "2022"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[06-Ano].[06-Ano].[2023]",
                      "caption": "2023"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes]",
            "levels": {
              "Mes": {
                "name": "Mes",
                "aggregators": [],
                "selection": {
                  "type": "EXCLUSION",
                  "members": [
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[JANEIRO]",
                      "caption": "JANEIRO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[FEVEREIRO]",
                      "caption": "FEVEREIRO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[MARÇO]",
                      "caption": "MARÇO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[ABRIL]",
                      "caption": "ABRIL"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[MAIO]",
                      "caption": "MAIO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[1º SEM].[JUNHO]",
                      "caption": "JUNHO"
                    },
                    {
                      "uniqueName": "[07-Mes].[07-Mes].[2º SEM].[JULHO]",
                      "caption": "JULHO"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[08-Dia].[08-Dia]",
            "levels": {
              "Dia Mes": {
                "name": "Dia Mes"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "nonEmpty": True,
        "aggregators": []
      }
    },
    "visualTotals": False,
    "visualTotalsPattern": None,
    "lowestLevelsOnly": False,
    "details": {
      "axis": "COLUMNS",
      "location": "BOTTOM",
      "measures": []
    },
    "calculatedMeasures": []
  },
  "queryType": "OLAP",
  "type": "QUERYMODEL",
  "cube": {
    "uniqueName": "[Prohort].[Prohort].[Prohort].[PROHORT - PRECO DIARIO]",
    "name": "PROHORT - PRECO DIARIO",
    "connection": "Prohort",
    "catalog": "Prohort",
    "schema": "Prohort",
    "caption": None,
    "visible": False
  },
  "mdx": None,
  "parameters": {},
  "plugins": {},
  "properties": {
    "saiku.olap.query.automatic_execution": False,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty": True,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.rows": True,
    "saiku.olap.query.nonempty.columns": True,
    "saiku.ui.render.mode": "table",
    "saiku.olap.query.filter": True,
    "saiku.olap.result.formatter": "flattened",
    "org.saiku.query.explain": True,
    "org.saiku.connection.scenario": False,
    "saiku.olap.query.drillthrough": True
  },
  "metadata": {}
})

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
  'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


session = requests.Session()

cookie_data = {
   'username': 'almir.costa',
   'password': '123123'
}

cookie_url = 'https://dw.ceasa.gov.br/saiku/rest/saiku/session'
response = session.post(cookie_url, data=cookie_data)

url = "https://dw.ceasa.gov.br/saiku/rest/saiku/api/query/execute"
response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)


I dont have neither a username nor a password for the site. I tried your code as is and the output was 500 Internal Server Error. I also tried using the payload of my code as the data on your code, but the response was 403

@Ramiro this is not my username/password, it is hardcoded in the site, try the code on it's own you should get a response 200 with no content, but it has one cookie JSESSIONID.

okay, just tried and it worked, thank you! Could you explain how do i implement the rest of my code to yours. Its the first time that i'm trying to web-scrape

@Ramiro check the edit, I added the full code.

it worked, thank you so much for the lesson.
